# Are "Creep up" and "Climb up" phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, particle-shift

In the phrases "Creeping up the backstairs" or "Climbing up the wall",
is *up*  only a preposition, or is it part of a phrasal verb?

Comment: Can we get a bit more clarity on what you mean? The short answer to your headline question is no, they're not phrasal verbs - their meaning can be recovered from the meaning of the verb + preposition. An example of a phrasal verb is _look after_, where it has nothing to do with taking care of something/one.

Comment: You can't say *"he crept it up"* or *"he climbed it up"*, and the meaning is fairly obvious from the combination of the verb and the preposition, so: no.

Comment: The definitions of 'phrasal verbs' are several and contradictory. But these two strings are V + Prep, non-unitary.

Answer (score 7):

The test to distinguish a

> [`Verb` + `[Prepositional Phrase]`]

constituent from a

> [`[Phrasal Verb]` + `Object`]

constituent uses the syntactic rule of [Particle Shift, which applies only to phrasal verbs](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf).

The test works like this: true transitive phrasal verbs like *look up* in its 'research' sense govern  the syntactic alternation that produces these two synonymous grammatical sentences:

- *I **looked up** the word in a dictionary.*
- *I **looked** the word **up** in a dictionary.*

The "particle" (which is a question-begging term for the "preposition part" of a phrasal verb)
may appear either **before** or **after** the direct object noun phrase, at the speaker's choice.
There is no difference except pronunciation between these two variants.  Further examples:

- *They **burned up/down** the barn. ~ They **burned** the barn **up/down**.*
- *She **drank up/down** her coffee. ~  She **drank** her coffee **up/down**.*

By comparison, real prepositional phrases do not allow the object to appear before the preposition:

- *He looked up the staircase,* but not **He looked the staircase up.*

Applying this test to the original example phrases, we find that

- *The ivy is creeping up the backstairs*, but not **The ivy is creeping the backstairs up.*
- *The ivy is climbing up the wall,* but not **The ivy is climbing the wall up.*

So the syntax lab results show that these are **not** phrasal verbs (because they fail the test),
but rather verbs modified by prepositional phrases.

The situation is even more definitive with a pronoun object; phrasal verbs **require** Particle Shift
with pronoun objects, so we get very clear contrasts like

- *That's the dictionary I looked it up in*
  ~
  **That's the dictionary I looked up it in.*
  but
- **The back wall, the ivy is climbing it up*
  ~
  *The back wall, the ivy is climbing up it.*

Comment: Does this mean that _look after_ in _‘She looks after her children/them’_ would not be considered a phrasal verb?

Comment: Since you can't say **She looks her children after,* then, yes, it's not a phrasal verb. Transitive phrasal verbs are easy to determine with this test; intransitive ones are harder because there's no direct object. But final stress (stressed particle) is a good test, too. `Verb + PPhrase` constructions stress the verb, rather than the preposition.

Comment: There are, of course, times when because the meaning of the verb can differ, the construction can be either a phrasal verb or a verb + pp: *He tore up the runway.*

Comment: Nice example. The particle-shifted version _He tore the runway up_ can't express fast driving, but can only express excavation. This indicates that _tear up `Path`_ is a prepositional idiom, whereas _tear up_ is a phrasal verb idiom with a completely different meaning. At least that's true when _tear up_ is pronounced /ter/; when it's pronounced /tir/ the identically spelled phrasal verb _tear up_ means to have one's eyes fill with tears (whether they escape to the face or not). That one's intransitive but can be identified because of the stress on _up_.

Comment: I feel that 'this takes one definition of "phrasal verb" that is not universally accepted' needs adding. [Claridge, in _Multi-word Verbs in Early Modern English ..._](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Multi_word_Verbs_in_Early_Modern_English.html?id=8kfvotMI5hYC&redir_esc=y), seeks to clarify the situation. 'Look after' = 'mind, tend, care for' would be classed by her as a MWV.